# Delegate FolderListModel in TableView

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I'm learning Qt Quick to make a file manager, but I have no experience in QML or GUI in general. The first step is to list the content of a folder, using `FolderListModel`. I got the [example code](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-folderlistmodel-folderlistmodel.html) working using `ListView`, but naturally I want to display multiple fields in addition to the name, e.g. size, time, and so on. Thus, I'm thinking of using `TableView`.

However, it's not clear to me how to delegate each entry as a row in `TableView`. Currently I'm simply using `itemDelegate` to display `fileName`, and the resultant is that in each row, all the columns repeat the name of the entry. So I think [`rowDelegate`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html#rowDelegate-prop) is the correct way, but how do I make a proper delegate `Component` for that purpose? Conceptually I'd like to specify an array of fields, e.g. `[model.fileName, model.fileSize]` corresponding to the table columns. Is this achievable?

For clarify I'm posting the code below:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 2.1

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 900
    height: 600
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Item {
        anchors.fill: parent

        width: 900
        height: 600

        SplitView {
            id: splitView1
            anchors.fill: parent

            TabView {
                id: tabView1
                width: splitView1.width / 2

                Tab {
                    title: qsTr("Home")

                    TableView {
                        id: tableView1
                        width: splitView1.width / 2

                        TableViewColumn {
                            role: "name"
                            title: qsTr("Name")
                            width: tableView1.width * 0.75
                        }

                        TableViewColumn {
                            role: "size"
                            title: qsTr("Size")
                            width: tableView1.width * 0.25
                        }

                        FolderListModel {
                            id: folderModel2
                            folder: "file:/home/username"
                            nameFilters: ["*"]
                            showHidden: true

                        }

                        Component {
                            id: fileDelegate2
                            Text {
                                text: model.fileName
                            }
                        }

                        model: folderModel2
                        itemDelegate: fileDelegate2
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-folderlistmodel-folderlistmodel.html#details) mentions that the following roles are available:

> - List item
> - fileName
> - filePath
> - fileURL (since Qt 5.2)
> - fileBaseName
> - fileSuffix
> - fileSize
> - fileModified
> - fileAccessed
> - fileIsDir

So you don't need to have custom delegates to display that information, just set the `role` property of `TableViewColumn` appropriately:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 2.1

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 900
    height: 600
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Item {
        anchors.fill: parent

        width: 900
        height: 600

        SplitView {
            id: splitView1
            anchors.fill: parent

            TabView {
                id: tabView1
                width: splitView1.width / 2

                Tab {
                    title: qsTr("Home")

                    TableView {
                        id: tableView1
                        width: splitView1.width / 2

                        TableViewColumn {
                            role: "fileName"
                            title: qsTr("Name")
                            width: tableView1.width * 0.75
                        }

                        TableViewColumn {
                            role: "fileSize"
                            title: qsTr("Size")
                            width: tableView1.width * 0.25
                        }

                        FolderListModel {
                            id: folderModel2
                            folder: "file:/home/username"
                            nameFilters: ["*"]
                            showHidden: true

                        }

                        model: folderModel2
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```