# Folder navigation by double-click in TableView

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I'm learning Qt Quick to write a file manager. Following the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33517328/3478591) to my previous question, now I'm trying to navigate around the directory tree by double-clicking a row (corresponding to a folder) in `TableView`, that is, the view should change to the content inside the folder that I just double-clicked.

Conceptually, I'll need to tell `onDoubleClicked` to change the `folder` property of `FolderListModel`, right? But it's not clear to me how to get the model element corresponding to the clicked row? A hard-coded example would be:

```
TableView {
    onDoubleClicked: {
        folderModel2.folder = "file:///bin";
    }
}
```

But I want to assign to the `folder` property the role [`fileURL`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-folderlistmodel-folderlistmodel.html#details) of the model element corresponding to the row I double-clicked. By the way I'm not planing to explicitly display `fileURL` in the `TableView`, so I'll have to get the model element itself, not just the view.

Again the starting code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33517328/3478591). Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It felt like a daunting thing for me, walking in the dark, but after I wrote the question up, it became clearer what exactly to look up. So far a working solution:

```
TableView {
    onDoubleClicked: {
        var cur_idx = tableView1.currentRow;
        if ( folderModel2.isFolder(cur_idx) ) {
            folderModel2.folder = folderModel2.get(cur_idx, "fileURL");
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if there are better solutions, or if my current code has malpractices in term of QML. Thanks for reading.

Comment: I don't think there's any other way to do this from QML, and it looks fine to me, good work. :)