# Set Loader item property

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

In the [context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513546/delegate-folderlistmodel-in-tableview) of a file manager, I have a `TableView` component saved in the file `dirview.qml`, which displays the content of some directory using `FolderListModel`:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 2.1

TableView {
    id: tableView
    property string folder_url: "file:///tmp"
    anchors.fill: parent

    TableViewColumn {
        role: "fileName"
        title: qsTr("Name")
        width: tableView.width * 0.7
    }

    TableViewColumn {
        role: "fileURL"
        title: qsTr("Size")
        width: tableView.width * 0.2
    }

    FolderListModel {
        id: folderModel
        folder: folder_url
        nameFilters: ["*"]
        showHidden: true
        showDirsFirst: true
        showDotAndDotDot: true
    }

    model: folderModel
}
```

Now in `main.qml`, I want to load this component in a `Tab`. Since `Tab` is a `Loader`, I can do the following:

```
TabView {
    id: tabView2

    Tab {
        title: qsTr("Home")
        source: "dirview.qml"
    }
}
```

However, what I need to do is somehow passing a URL string in order to set the `folder_url` property of the `dirview.qml` component, and that string must overwrite the default value `file:///tmp` (so some kind of "binding" I'm talking about).

I tried a few things that didn't work, such as using `Tab.onLoaded` to set `item.folder_url = "file:///home"`. The view doesn't change.

What is the right way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Loader.item`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#item-prop) property to access `Tab` object. According to the documentation:

> This property holds the top-level object that is currently loaded

For example:

```
Tab {
    title: qsTr("Home")
    source: "dirview.qml"
    onLoaded: {
        item.folder_url = "file:/home"
    }
}
```

Comment: indeed it works fine and it is the correct way. Maybe he used the wrong path? It would be nice if you can also advice the OP for the usage of `alias`: that's a good place where to use it. E.g. he could write `property alias folder: folderModel.folder` in place of the current usage of a new property.

Comment: Thank you so much! It was indeed due to an invalid path, but I was suspecting that `onLoaded` wasn't the right handler, so overlooked the trivial mistake. And I'm using `property alias` now instead. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: What if I need to use the property on the item's completion? (Component.onCompleted inside TableView as opposed to onLoaded inside Tab)