# Get active Tab from TabView and change item property

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

In the [context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33536881/set-loader-item-property) of a dual-pane file manager, I have two `TabView` items side by side, each contains multiple tabs of course, and each `Tab` loads a `TableView` showing the content of a specific directory using `FolderListModel`.

```
SplitView
    TabView
        Tab
        Tab
    TabView
        Tab
```

My current task is to implement a toolbar button to toggle the `showHidden` property of the `FolderListModel` instance shown in the **active** tab. Therefore, I need a way to find out what the currently active tab is.

Next, once I get the active `Tab`, I need to change `Tab.item.some_property`, in particular, the property of interest is `show_hidden`, which is an alias to the `showHidden` property of the underlying `FolderListModel`. For example, a hard-coded scenario would be:

```
ToolButton {
    onClicked: {
        tab1.item.show_hidden = false;
        tab1.destroy();  // need "refresh" instead
    }
}
```

First I need to get `tab1` based on whether it is active, and second, after I change `show_hidden`, the view doesn't refresh by itself, so I need to call some kind of reload function, but which? Or maybe reload isn't the best way to do it? Is it possible to do it using a custom signal handler? (Again I can only think conceptually without knowing how to implement it.)

As suggested I'm posting a running example below:

```
/* main.qml */
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 1280
    height: 700

    toolBar: ToolBar {
        RowLayout {
            anchors.fill: parent

            ToolButton {
                onClicked: {    // TODO toggle folderModel.showHidden property
                    tab1A.item.show_hidden = false;
//                    tab1A.destroy();  // fixme how to refresh the view?
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Item {
        anchors.fill: parent

        SplitView {
            id: splitView
            anchors.fill: parent

            TabView {
                id: tabView1
                width: splitView.width / 2

                Tab {
                    id: tab1A

                    title: qsTr("Home")
                    source: "dirview.qml"

                    onLoaded: {
                        item.folder_url = "file:///tmp";
                    }
                }

                Tab {
                    title: qsTr("Folder")
                    source: "dirview.qml"
                    onLoaded: {
                        item.folder_url = "file:///home";
                    }
                }
            }

            TabView {
                id: tabView2

                Tab {
                    title: qsTr("Home")
                    source: "dirview.qml"
                    onLoaded: {
                        item.folder_url = "file:///home";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
/* dirview.qml */
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 2.1

TableView {
    property alias folder_url: folderModel.folder
    property alias show_hidden: folderModel.showHidden

    id: tableView
    anchors.fill: parent

    TableViewColumn {
        role: "fileName"
        title: qsTr("Name")
        width: tableView.width * 0.7
    }

    TableViewColumn {
        role: "fileSize"
        title: qsTr("Size")
        width: tableView.width * 0.2
    }

    FolderListModel {
        id: folderModel
        nameFilters: ["*"]
        showHidden: true
        showDirsFirst: true
        showDotAndDotDot: true
    }

    model: folderModel
}
```

Thank you.

---

Noticed something weird: `Tab.item.folder_url` has the right info, however, `Tab.item.show_hidden` is always `false`, even if I remove the line where I manually set it to `false`. This is hard to understand as I initially set `FolderListModel.showHidden` to `true` in `dirview.qml`.

```
ToolButton {
    onClicked: {    // TODO toggle folderModel.showHidden property
        var cur_tab_idx = tabView1.currentIndex;

        console.log(tabView1.getTab(cur_tab_idx).item.folder_url);
        console.log(tabView1.getTab(cur_tab_idx).item.show_hidden);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you'll have to provide a minimal, running example. Something with *one* `TabView`, so that we can see what's not "refreshing". The answer to your first question is: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tabview.html#currentIndex-prop

Comment: @Mitch Thanks for the hint regarding the active tab. However I realize that, because the toolbar button is shared by both "panes" (`TabView`), before getting the active tab, I need to know which pane is active, under `SplitView`. I don't see the latter provides any means to find out which of its children is active?

Comment: I don't get it. You only have one child in the `SplitView`..

Comment: @Mitch Sorry about that, the previous comment you posted mentioned "one `TabView`" so I did that, but didn't realize that I needed to demo the two-pane scenario. Change has been made. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an explanation of how I have got it to work.

I solved first problem using `focus` flag. When current `Tab` in `TabView` changes one `Tab` gains focus and the other one looses. So by using `onFocusChanged()` signal you can know exactly when one `Tab` becomes active or inactive.
The focus of `Tab` does not change when focus of whole `TabView` changes. Because of this I created an `Array` (named *tabs* in code) containing references to every `TabView` and `Tab` it contains. With this when `TabView` becomes inactive I can set `focus` of its `Tab` objects to `false` using simple `for`.

Second problem was more tricky. I see no other option of turning `showHidden` flag off than destroying and creating a new `FolderListModel`. We cannot (or I could not :) ) provide `model` to `TableView` dynamically so I made a `ListModel`. Advantage of regular `ListModel` compared to `FolderListModel` is that it can be cleared and refilled with data. Every time `folder_url` or `show_hidden` changes I destroy current `FolderListModel` and create a new one. After it is created I rewrite its data to the `ListModel`.

---

Here is the working code.

*main.qml*

```
/* main.qml */
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 1280
    height: 700

    property var tabs: [
        [tabView1, [tab1A, tab1B]],
        [tabView2, [tab2A]]
    ]

    toolBar: ToolBar {
        RowLayout {
            anchors.fill: parent

            ToolButton {
                onClicked: {    // TODO toggle folderModel.showHidden property
                    tab1A.item.show_hidden = false;
//                    tab1A.destroy();  // fixme how to refresh the view?
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Item {
        anchors.fill: parent

        SplitView {
            id: splitView
            anchors.fill: parent

            TabView {
                id: tabView1
                width: splitView.width / 2

                Tab {
                    id: tab1A

                    title: qsTr("Home")
                    source: "dirview.qml"

                    onLoaded: {
                        item.folder_url = "file:///tmp";
                    }
                    onFocusChanged: {
                        item.show_hidden = focus
                    }
                }
                onFocusChanged: {
                    if (!focus)
                        for (var i = 0 ; i < tabs[0][1].length ; i++)
                            tabs[0][1][i].focus = false
                }

                Tab {
                    id: tab1B
                    title: qsTr("Folder")
                    source: "dirview.qml"
                    onLoaded: {
                        item.folder_url = "file:///home";
                    }
                    onFocusChanged: {
                        item.show_hidden = focus
                    }
                }
            }

            TabView {
                id: tabView2

                Tab {
                    id: tab2A
                    title: qsTr("Home")
                    source: "dirview.qml"
                    onLoaded: {
                        item.folder_url = "file:///tmp";
                    }
                    onFocusChanged: {
                        item.show_hidden = focus
                    }
                }
                onFocusChanged: {
                    if (!focus)
                        for (var i = 0 ; i < tabs[1][1].length ; i++)
                            tabs[1][1][i].focus = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

*dirview.qml*

```
/* dirview.qml */
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 2.1

TableView {
    property string folder_url
    property bool show_hidden

    id: tableView
    anchors.fill: parent

    TableViewColumn {
        role: "fileName"
        title: qsTr("Name")
        width: tableView.width * 0.7
    }

    TableViewColumn {
        role: "fileSize"
        title: qsTr("Size")
        width: tableView.width * 0.2
    }

    ListModel {
        id: secondListModel
    }

    property var fm
    property int folderModelCount

    onFolder_urlChanged: {
        reloadFolderModel()
    }
    onShow_hiddenChanged: {
        reloadFolderModel()
    }

    onFolderModelCountChanged: {
        resetSecondListModel()
    }

    function reloadFolderModel() {
        folderModelCount = 0
        if (typeof(fm) !== "undefined")
            fm.destroy()

        var component = Qt.createComponent("foldermodel.qml")
        if (component.status === Component.Ready)
            fm = component.createObject(
                        tableView, {"folder_url": folder_url, "show_hidden": show_hidden})
        else
            console.error(component.errorString())

        folderModelCount =
                Qt.binding(function(){return fm.folderModel.count})
    }

    function resetSecondListModel() {
        secondListModel.clear()
        for (var i = 0 ; i < folderModelCount ; i++) {
            secondListModel.append({
                                       "fileName": fm.folderModel.get(i, "fileName"),
                                       "filePath": fm.folderModel.get(i, "filePath"),
                                       "fileURL": fm.folderModel.get(i, "fileURL"),
                                       "fileBaseName": fm.folderModel.get(i, "fileBaseName"),
                                       "fileSuffix": fm.folderModel.get(i, "fileSuffix"),
                                       "fileSize": fm.folderModel.get(i, "fileSize"),
                                       "fileModified": fm.folderModel.get(i, "fileModified"),
                                       "fileAccessed": fm.folderModel.get(i, "fileAccessed"),
                                       "fileIsDir": fm.folderModel.get(i, "fileIsDir")
                                   })
        }
    }

    model: secondListModel
}
```

---

*foldermodel.qml* (add this file)

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 2.1

Item {
    property string folder_url
    property bool show_hidden
    property alias folderModel: folderModelObject
    FolderListModel {
        id: folderModelObject
        nameFilters: ["*"]
        folder: folder_url
        showHidden: show_hidden
        showDirsFirst: true
        showDotAndDotDot: true
    }
}
```

---

Now you understand why QML is not very flexible. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's educational to see how custom event handlers can be defined in JavaScript. By saying "QML is not very flexible", do you mean comparing to using Qt Widgets in C++? Or you are talking about the limitation of the models like `FolderListModel`? In the latter case, it's less trouble to define a custom model in Qt/C++? A demo would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've been wondering, instead of destroying the model, is there a way simply destroy and re-create the view instead? From my observation, it's not that `FolderListModel.showHidden` cannot be toggled back and forth, but somehow the `TableView` cannot properly update its rows (removing hidden entries) when `showHidden` is changed to `false`. Is there a way to refresh the view?

Comment: I don't think Qt/C++ is superior than QML. Then there would be no point in working with QML. Yes, I am talking about the limitation of the components. Sometimes there will be no other way than work around. By demo you mean working example? If so you can just create new project, create 3 files as in the answer and copy their body.

Comment: Regarding the question how to get the current tab in the active pane, I figured out a solution that doesn't require keeping track of all the tabs (later on users should be able to create and destroy tabs as well). Basically the task is to get the active pane, once that's done, we can simply use `TabView.getTab(TabView.currentIndex)` to find the current tab. I'll post the code as an partial answer below.

Comment: Answering you second comment: There is no problem in recreating the whole structures of objects. You can create dynamically objects by using `Component` object, creating object from separate file or a string. [More info here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html)  
Answering last comment: Glad to hear it. Use whatever approach that suits you.

Comment: By demo I meant that, since you [mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33576926/writing-a-file-manager-in-qml) that you'd switched to Qt/C++ for your file manager, I wonder if this problem is easier to solve in Qt/C++?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to share the code. (However here you can see what it takes to make a model in C++)[http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html] 

I have tested `FolderListModel` without the `TabView` and the problem was the same. Enabling `showHidden` flag shows more files but disabling it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to finding the current `Tab` in the active `TabView` (pane): declare a property of `SplitView` to store the `TabView` that has `activeFocus`.

A `StatusBar` is added to demo the functionality.

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 1280
    height: 700

    toolBar: ToolBar {
        RowLayout {
            anchors.fill: parent

            ToolButton {
                onClicked: {    // TODO toggle folderModel.showHidden property
                    // Demo: get the current tab of the active pane
                    var active_pane = splitView.activePane;
                    var cur_tab_idx = active_pane.currentIndex;
                    var cur_tab_item = active_pane.getTab(cur_tab_idx).item;
                    testLabel.text = cur_tab_item.folder_url;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    SplitView {
        id: splitView

        property TabView activePane: tabView1

        anchors.fill: parent

        TabView {
            id: tabView1
            width: splitView.width / 2

            onActiveFocusChanged: {
                if (activeFocus) {
                    splitView.activePane = tabView1;
                }
            }

            Tab {
                title: qsTr("tmp")
                source: "dirview.qml"
                onLoaded: {
                    item.folder_url = "file:///tmp";
                }
            }

            Tab {
                title: qsTr("home")
                source: "dirview.qml"
                onLoaded: {
                    item.folder_url = "file:///home";
                }
            }
        }

        TabView {
            id: tabView2

            onActiveFocusChanged: {
                if (activeFocus) {
                    splitView.activePane = tabView2;
                }
            }

            Tab {
                title: qsTr("bin")
                source: "dirview.qml"
                onLoaded: {
                    item.folder_url = "file:///bin";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    statusBar: StatusBar {
        RowLayout {
            Label {
                text: (splitView.activePane === tabView1) ? "Pane 1" : "Pane 2"
            }
            Label {
                id: testLabel
            }
        }
    }
}
```