# Writing a file manager in QML

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I just started learning QML, with no previous experience in Qt or GUI development in general. My first task is to write a file manager. So far what I like about QML is that I can do design in plain text, but it's been quite [challenging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33550034/drag-and-drop-rows-in-tableview) finding the way around to achieve even simple things. Currently I use `Qt.labs.FolderListModel 2.1` as the work horse for directory listing, and I haven't even touched C++ or PyQt yet, it's purely QML now.

So I have a few questions regarding the future path of my little file manager:

1. Is `FolderListModel` powerful enough to do all the things a
   versatile file manager can do? As far as I see,
   [`QFileSystemModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html) looks more feature complete? And the fact
   that the former is in `Qt.labs` worries me a bit. If indeed
   `FolderListModel` is meant to be used as a "quick-and-dirty" thing,
   does that mean that it's better to switch to `QFileSystemModel`
   sooner? Since I approached the Qt world from QML rather than the
   traditional C++ angle, what is it like to replace my current
   `FolderListModel` code in QML to something backed by Qt/C++ or PyQt?
2. Related: I heard that it's actually possible to write complete applications in pure QML (with JavaScript). If the application is driven by some back-end, e.g. a database, I can see that QML alone is probably not expressive enough. However, in my case of writing a file manager, despite the "performance" argument, is it a good idea to try to stick to pure QML, using JavaScript for all the business logic?

Comment: You have mentioned several times now that you find it difficult to do things in QML. I wonder what these things are, and if you're attempting tasks that are too advanced for beginners, and starting off with simpler ones would help. Also, this question has a lot of questions within it, some of which (especially the second) are quite opinion-based. You might get better help for questions like these on the mailing list.

Comment: 1) AFAIK it is inside "labs" because it is somewhat still missing features. Hence, no, it's not powerful enough. I think you should try C++/QML with something simpler, though. 2) it depends. A lot of stuff can be done in QML. The thing is, you typically split business logic and UI to better structure and maintain the code. BUT you are trying to learn QML, not creating the best file manager around. Starts off with just that. You have scratched the surface here, trust me. :)

Comment: I've patched QFolderListModel by adding some properties, and AFAIR it uses QFileSystemModel under the hood. I hope if you some features are missing you  will patch FolderListModel and report changes to the upstream.

Comment: @Mitch One of the difficulties for me is to figure out how to make the rows in `TableView` [drag-able](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33550034/drag-and-drop-rows-in-tableview). @BaCaRoZzo I'll definitely look into C++ models that can be used in QML.

Answer (score 1):

I have been working recently on a simple file manager in QML. The problems you will face if you stick only to QML are:

- not being able to know how many drives are currently plugged in.
- not being able to easily sort files by name. Using provided sorting flags will result in having *B.txt* before *a.txt* because of the case.

Fortunately it is easy to connect C++ classes with QML so you will always be able to expand default QML features.

How to connect C++ and QML: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html

Comment: Thanks! Are you using `FolerListModel` or `QFileSystemModel`, or a custom-made model? If you used `FolderListModel` before, did you notice that once you set `showHidden` to `true` (which does update the view correspondingly), and then you set it to `false`, the view is not updated anymore? Do you know a workaround? The related question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33557271/get-active-tab-from-tabview-and-change-item-property).

Comment: I used custom model (`QAbstractListModel`) with information from `QDir`. Unfortunately I was not displaying hidden files. However that problem seems is interesting. Maybe `showHidden` flag was not meant to be toggled during application runtime.